# Имеется диалоговое окошко в которой клиент может искать инфу введя

Tags: java, android

Имеется диалоговое окошко в которой клиент может искать инфу введя в `EditText` ключевое слово и нажав на кнопку Search. Проблема состоит в том, что данный запрос нормально отправляется и результат нормально получается, НО в поле, где должны выводиться эти результаты, вывести не могу, вернее данное поле обновляется только после спуска KeyPad-а, а мне нужно чтоб при нажатии на кнопку выводились результаты поиска. Как это всё можно организовать?

Answer (score 2):

Для поиска есть специальная вьюха - *SearchView*

Comment: Старайтесь писать более развернутые ответы согласно [справке и правилам сайта](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: а в чем принципиальная разница между SearchView и EditText ?

Comment: @SalutAmigo 1. очень просто внедрить в тулбар; 2. при поиске keyboard сама скроется; + это лучше, чем велосипедить.